# What is the difference between remove-erase and find-erase

Tags: c++, stl

Suppose you want to remove a single element from a vector by value. What is the difference between [remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)-erase:

```
vector<int> v;
// add some values
vector<int>::iterator it = remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);
v.erase(it);
```

And find-erase

```
vector<int> v;
// add some values
vector<int>::iterator it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);
if(it != v.end())
{
  v.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: A better answer is provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011627/erasing-using-iterator-from-find-or-remove

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your remove-erase code is not correct. The remove-erase idiom looks like this:

```
vector<int>::iterator it = remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);
v.erase(it, v.end());
```

In that case, it has the effect of erasing all values equal to 5 but it minimises the amount of copying required to achieve that.

Your find-erase code removes only the first value equal to 5, so it does what you want.

Your remove-erase code moves all the values not equal to 5 to the front of the vector (that's what `std::remove` does), erases one of the remaining elements of the vector, and leaves any remaining elements after that with unspecified values (which is also what `remove` does). It has undefined behavior if the vector doesn't contain a `5` to begin with, because `remove` would return `v.end()` in that case.

So, if you only want to erase a single element of several equal to 5 then `std::remove` is no use to you because it doesn't preserve the (other) 5s. If you want to move the non-5 values to the start and the 5 values to the end, before removing the first of the 5s, then you could in fact do that with `std::partition` just not with `std::remove`:

```
auto it = partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i) { return i != 5; });
if (it != v.end()) v.erase(it);
```

Although, since one 5 is as good as another you get the same result by erasing the last of the 5s rather than the first, and it's more efficient when there's more than one of them:

```
auto it = partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i) { return i != 5; });
if (it != v.end()) v.pop_back();
```

If you can somehow be sure that the vector initially contains *exactly* one element equal to 5 (no more or less), then your two bits of code do the same thing. And in that case you wouldn't need the test for `it != v.end()` in the find-erase code, you would know it isn't equal. You could just do `v.erase(find(v.begin(), v.end(), 5))`.

Comment: hm, nice mentioning the standard erase idiom; but OP actually only **wants** to delete **one** occurence

Answer (score 1):

The difference would be that if there is more than one value matching the given one, the `remove` solution will move all of the non-matching items to the start (thanks to Steve Jessop for pointing it out in the comments). Only `erase` will then remove the first occurence of these; and you end up with a re-sorted `vector`, containing one less of the given value.

The `find`- solution would only remove the first occurence, and not change the order of the vector.

Comment: `remove` doesn't move the equal values to the end, it moves the non-equal values to the start. What's left at the end is unspecified.

Answer (score -1):

Did you actually try to see the difference?

In the first piece of code, `std::remove` transforms the vector by placing **all** the elements that are equal to 5 to the end of the vector and returns the iterator to the *new* end. When you call `erase` then you remove the first element after the new end. You probably want to do:

```
vector<int>::iterator it = remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);
v.erase(it, v.end());
```

That would remove all the elements with value 5.

In the second example, `std::find` finds the first element of the vector that is equal to 5 and returns an iterator to it. Calling `erase` will only remove that element.

That is the difference.

Comment: He's calling the single parameter version of erase, so only one element is ever erased.

Comment: Calling `erase` on the first piece of code will only erase the first of the removed elements.

Comment: yes, I noticed that but you guys were too fast while I was editing my answer