# Erasing using iterator from 'find' or 'remove'

Tags: c++, vector, std

I would like to know what's the best practice to remove an element from a vector in C++.

I have seen many times people using std::remove to find and delete the element, and then using erase to remove the element from the vector.

But why is it better than using find to get the iterator of the element you want to remove and then using the erase with that iterator?

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`std::find` followed by `vector::erase` will erase the first occurrence of an object with the given value from the `vector`.

```
std::vector<int> vec{1,3,3,8,3,5};
vec.erase(std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 3));
//vec == {1,3,8,3,5}
```

`std::remove` followed by `vector::erase` will remove *every* occurrence of an object with the given value from the `vector`.

```
std::vector<int> vec{1,3,3,8,3,5};
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 3), vec.end());
//vec == {1,8,5}
```

Neither is better, they just do different things.

`std::remove` is more generally useful, and that is why it is more often seen; in particular, `std::remove` followed by `vector::erase` does nothing when the element is not present in the vector, while `std::find` followed by `vector::erase` has undefined behavior.

Note that both "find-erase", "remove-erase" maintain the relative order of the elements. If you want to remove an element from the vector but do not care about the resulting order of the elements, you can use "find-move-pop_back" or "partition-erase":

```
//find-move-pop_back
std::vector<int> vec{1,3,3,8,3,5};
*std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 3) = std::move(vec.back());
vec.pop_back();

//partition-erase
std::vector<int> vec{1,3,3,8,3,5};
vec.erase(
    std::partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](int v){return v != 3;}),
    vec.end());
```

Comment: Note that partition-erase will remove elements for which predicate returns false, and remove-erase will remove elements for which predicate returns true.